# Break MAMP Pro host/db association

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, mamp

I have started developing using Valet and must use port 80 for that. This collides with MAMP Pro's Apache on port 80, so when I need Valet running I change the port for MAMP's apache to port 81. I could simply shut down MAMP all together I suppose, but I still need MySQL running. This isn't a big deal though - I usually work for a full week on Valet at a time which means very little hassle.

However it creates another big hassle; Each time I change the port, MAMP goes through each database and changes the port (somewhere, not sure...), specifically on the WordPress installs that exist. This is annoying because it's not a persistent change, and it takes a long time to do. Also completely useless since all WP sites I work on, have their url's set statically in `wp-config.php`.

I believe MAMP does this because I have had the hosts tethered to one or more databases. I have now unchecked all databases on all hosts, but this behaviour still persists.

Does anyone know how I stop this behaviour?

Comment: "Does anyone know how I stop this behavior?" - Permenantly move one of those services to another port. Running something like Apache on another port is typically seamless.

Comment: Not an option. Moving apache to anything other than port 80 becomes problematic when developing WP Multisites, and Valet needs to be run on port 80.